# I can`t open my file in Vs Code, i try to reinstall app, turn off all references

Tags: visual-studio-code

My file is located on the path node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss
Everything worked fine before, but now something is broken. When I write /node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss the development environment finds this file but the code gives an error. If the code loads these files because it knows about their location, it means that they need to be taken from node_modules. In short, I can’t follow the link to the bootstrap/scss/bootstrap file, although I could before, but in the code itself it works fine, I checkedenter image description here. For some reason it is looking in the current folder, which is located along the path app/assets/stylsheets, although this has never happened before.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)